# Конструктор слайдер карусель

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

Всем привет. Есть конструктор слайдера-карусели, сейчас пытаюсь добавить точки и обозначение типа "01/04" в зависимости от текущего сайта. Направьте на правильный путь, начал с точками, но работает некорректно.
Спасибо

```js
        //Создаем шаблон
    (function(){
        //Для document и индекса создаем переменные
        var doc = document,
            index = 1;
        //Определяем конструктор слайдера
        var Slider = function() {
            //Определяем контейнер слайдера как свойство
            this.box = doc.querySelector('.carousel-container');
            //Определяем контейнер-обертку слайдов как свойство
            this.slidesBox = doc.querySelector('.carousel-slides');
            //Определяем непосредственно слайды как свойства
            this.slides = doc.querySelectorAll('.slide');
            //Определяем кнопки как свойства
            this.btns = doc.querySelectorAll('.btn');
            //Получаем значение ширины главного контейнера
            this.size = this.box.clientWidth;
            //Определяем точки
            this.dots = doc.querySelectorAll('.dot');
            
            
            
            //Вызываем методы внутри контейнера
            this.position();
            this.carousel();
            this.currentSlide();
        }
        
        //Создаем методы для слайдера
        //1. Метод для перемещения картинок на одну влево, чтобы первая картинка оказалась на своем месте
        Slider.prototype.position = function() {
            var size = this.size;
            this.slidesBox.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * size}px)`;
        };
        
        //2. Метод переключения
        Slider.prototype.carousel = function() {
            var i, max = this.btns.length,
                that = this;
            for(i = 0; i < max; i += 1) {
                that.btns[i].addEventListener('click', Slider[that.btns[i].id].bind(null, that))//Slider[id кнопок, для вызова статических методов] bind - передача аргументов в статические функции, т.к. статические методы не имеют доступа в пространство конструктора, не видят его свойства
            }
        };
    
    
    //3. Создаем статичные методы для кнопок
    Slider.prev = function(box) {
        box.slidesBox.style.transition = 'transform .3s ease-in-out';
        var size = box.size;
        var dots = box.dots;
        index <= 0 ? false : index--;
        box.slidesBox.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * size}px)`;
        for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i += 1) {
            dots[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
        index <= 0 ? false : dots[index - 1].classList.add('active');
        box.jump();
    };
    
    Slider.next = function(box) {
        box.slidesBox.style.transition = 'transform .3s ease-in-out';
        var max = box.slides.length;
        var size = box.size;
        var dots = box.dots;
        index >= max - 1 ? false : index++;
        box.slidesBox.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * size}px)`;
        for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i += 1) {
            dots[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
        index >= max - 1 ? false : dots[index - 1].classList.add('active');
        box.jump();
    };
    
    
    
    //Создаем метод для плавного перехода изображений
    Slider.prototype.jump = function() {
        var that = this;
        var size = this.size;
        this.slidesBox.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
            that.slides[index].id === 'firstClone' ? index = 1 : index;
            that.slides[index].id === 'lastClone' ? index = that.slides.length - 2 : index;
            that.slidesBox.style.transition = 'none';
            that.slidesBox.style.transform = `translateX(${-index * size}px)`;
        });
        
    };
    
    Slider.prototype.currentSlide = function() {
        var i, dots = this.dots;
        var that = this;
        for(i = 0; i < dots.length; i += 1) {
            dots[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                that.carousel();
            });
        }
    };
    
    //Вызываем конструктор
    new Slider();
    
    })();
```

```css
    .carousel-container {
    display: block;
    width: 640px;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-slides {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .slide {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(1) {
        left: 0;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(2) {
        left: 100%;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(3) {
        left: 200%;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(4) {
        left: 300%;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(5) {
        left: 400%;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(6) {
        left: 500%;
    }
    .btn-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255,138,24,0.5);
    }
    .btn {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dots-container {
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 80px;
    }
    .dot {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel-slides">
            <img class="slide" id="lastClone" src="4.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="1.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="2.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="3.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="4.jpg">
            <img class="slide" id="firstClone" src="1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <div class="btn" id="prev"> prev </div>
            <div class="btn" id="next"> next </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dots-container">
            <div class="dot active"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```